# How to prevent session hijacking with JSON web tokens

Tags: jwt

I've been studying web tokens as part of an app I'm building, and I'm trying to figure out how you would prevent someone from stealing the token and using it wherever they want. Especially if the token gets transmitted via plaintext.

Also, how would I prevent replay attacks and cross site request forgery? Are there other mechanisms that take care of these problems?

Comment: Hmm, so does no one actually understand JSON web tokens?

Comment: It's a question I've been trying to answer myself! Curious did you find an answer?